# write a .bat script to logout users with idle time more than 1 hour

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

I am trying to write a .bat script which will logout users  after 24 hours of being idle from Remote Desktop. The script works fine till 59 minutes but unable to perform the same operation in hours. Unable to do the conversion. Here it will logout idle users after 5 mins.

```
@echo off
:Top
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=,: " %%a in ('query user ^| find /i "disc"') do if %%d GTR 5 (logoff %%b) else %%e GTR 5 (logoff %%b)
choice /T 120 /C 1 /D 1 /N
goto top
```

if it exceeds 24 hours, it idle time would look like this:
[image]

I want to cover this scenario as well because this batch script will be running every four hours from a task scheduler.

Comment: What idle value does it display for a user when idle for long periods? I cannot test it as I only have my system, but if you can share that, I would probably be able to help.

Comment: The idle value if more than 59 mins is displayed as 1:29

Comment: ok, and you want it to loggof at 24:00 ?

Comment: It can be  23:59

Comment: If you run it every 4 hours and you leave untouched an account which has been disconnected for 59 minutes, then the maximum disconnection period cannot exceed 4hrs 59 minutes, _(perhaps 5 hours for safety)_.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try, I only assigned `%%e` to `val` as that is the token place on my system, so feel free to set `val=%%d` if your idle time is at that time. I cannot test this as I mentioned as I do not have the same environment.

```
@echo off
:Top
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=,: " %%a in ('query user ^| find /i "disc"') do set "val=%%e"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ("%val%") do if %%i GEQ 23 if %%j GTR 58 logoff %%b
choice /T 120 /C 1 /D 1 /N
goto top
```

Comment: I tried something like this: @echo off
:Top
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=,: " %%a in ('query user ^| find /i "disc"') do set "val=%%e"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%i in ("%val%") do if %%i GEQ 1 if %%j GTR 01 logoff %%b
choice /T 120 /C 1 /D 1 /N
goto top                                                                                                                                But it failed to logout the user

Comment: and that user has been idle for more than 1 hour?

Comment: Yes it has been idle for more than an hour

Answer (score 0):

The following is a powershell script to do the job:

`````powershell
if($server -eq $null){
    $server = "localhost"
}

$users = @()
# Query using quser, 2>$null to hide "No users exists...", then skip to the next server
$quser = quser /server:$server 2>$null
if(!($quser)){
    Continue
}

#Remove column headers
$quser = $quser[1..$($quser.Count)]
foreach($user in $quser){
    $usersObj = [PSCustomObject]@{Server=$null;Username=$null;SessionName=$null;SessionId=$Null;SessionState=$null;LogonTime=$null;IdleTime=$null}
    $quserData = $user -split "\s+"

    #We have to splice the array if the session is disconnected (as the SESSIONNAME column quserData[2] is empty)
    if(($user | select-string "Disc") -ne $null){
        #User is disconnected
        $quserData = ($quserData[0..1],"null",$quserData[2..($quserData.Length -1)]) -split "\s+"
    }

    # Server
    $usersObj.Server = $server
    # Username
    $usersObj.Username = $quserData[1]
    # SessionName
    $usersObj.SessionName = $quserData[2]
    # SessionID
    $usersObj.SessionID = $quserData[3]
    # SessionState
    $usersObj.SessionState = $quserData[4]
    # IdleTime
    $quserData[5] = $quserData[5] -replace "\+",":" -replace "\.","0:0" -replace "Disc","0:0"
    if($quserData[5] -like "*:*"){
        $usersObj.IdleTime = [timespan]"$($quserData[5])"
    }elseif($quserData[5] -eq "." -or $quserData[5] -eq "none"){
        $usersObj.idleTime = [timespan]"0:0"
    }else{
        $usersObj.IdleTime = [timespan]"0:$($quserData[5])"
    }
    # LogonTime
    $usersObj.LogonTime = (Get-Date "$($quserData[6]) $($quserData[7]) $($quserData[8] )")

    $users += $usersObj

   if($usersObj.idleTime -ge [timespan]"23:58" -and  $usersObj.SessionState -eq "Disc")
   {
    Logoff $quserData[3]
     }


}

return $users

}


$quer= Get-LoggedOnUsers````
`````